# collectd tail plugin ExcludeRegex Not Working

Tags: tail, collectd

Step 1.

```
LoadPlugin tail

<Plugin "tail">
  <File "/etc/nginx/access.log">
    <Match>
      Regex "HTTP/1..\" 4"
      ExcludeRegex "HTTP/1..\" 404"
      ExcludeRegex "HTTP/1..\" 499"
      DSType "CounterInc"
      Type "counter"
      Instance "4xx-excluded-404-and-499"
    </Match>
  </File>
</Plugin>
```

I am using collectd version 5.5.0. We then tried to collect the metrics for the status code of the Nginx access log using collectd's tail plugin. 
However, if you try to use ExcludeRegex "HTTP / 1 .. \" 404 and ExcludeRegex "HTTP / 1 .. \" 499 "as above, 'ExcludeRegex "HTTP/1..\" 499"' will work and ExcludeRegex 404 will not work.

I have found that it works well by creating separate Matches separately and using the corresponding ExcludeRegex. The following works well.

```
LoadPlugin tail

<Plugin "tail">
  <File "/etc/nginx/access.log">
    <Match>
      Regex "HTTP/1..\" 4"
      ExcludeRegex "HTTP/1..\" 404"
      DSType "CounterInc"
      Type "counter"
      Instance "4xx-excluded-404"
    </Match>
    <Match>
      Regex "HTTP/1..\" 4"
      ExcludeRegex "HTTP/1..\" 499"
      DSType "CounterInc"
      Type "counter"
      Instance "4xx-excluded-499"
    </Match>
  </File>
</Plugin>
```

However, the two did not work if they were in the same match.

Additionally, content of access.log is following patterns.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2016:18:44:15 +0900]  "GET /v3/intro HTTP/1.1" 200
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2016:18:44:15 +0900]  "GET /v3/intro HTTP/1.1" 404
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2016:18:44:15 +0900]  "GET /v3/intro HTTP/1.1" 499
```

Step 2.

```
<Plugin "tail">
  <File "/etc/nginx/access.log">
    <Match>
      Regex "HTTP/1..\" 4"
      ExcludeRegex "healthcheck"
      ExcludeRegex "HTTP/1..\" 499"
      DSType "CounterInc"
      Type "counter"
      Instance "4xx-excluded-404-and-499"
    </Match>
  </File>
</Plugin>
```

Second, I tried to test collectd with the above configuration. This time, I confirmed that Multi line ExcludeRegex is applied well. So, I think that if the same Regex is in it, I suspect that a problem may arise.

Why does not it work? Help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is an answer from github.

thank you for reporting this. It is, however, expected behavior and working as intended: there can be only one ExcludeRegex setting and if there are more then later ones overwrite the previous settings.

You can use the regex OR operator, |, so achieve your goal:

```
ExcludeRegex "HTTP/1..\" 404|HTTP/1..\" 404"
```

Or, shorter:

```
ExcludeRegex "HTTP/1..\" (404|499)"
```

Best regards,